# JPA: What's a good way to update data from an external source?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have some text files, from an external source, from which data is parsed. The output of the Java based parser is a list of Java objects representing the parsed data. The data objects have been annotated with JPA tags and are persisted into a database.

I receive regular updates to these text files, which may or may not have been changed. When the parser runs again on the updated data, it creates a new list of the objects. I need to consolidate the newer version of the objects with the ones already in the database. What is a good approach to figuring out what is different from the objects from the newly pared text files and what already exists in the database so that any updates or new data can be persisted?

Comment: Can your files be changed completely or you always know what part of a file is a subject of change?

Comment: I won't know what part's of the file changed. I'd basically need to apply some diff of the objects to see what has been changed.

Comment: In that case the best option would be to pick a corresponding object from your database by filename (and maybe version if you're using some DMS like Documentum or Sharepoint) and update it accordingly. You may also want to check if particular fields of that object were changed or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes should be able to just use merge().  As long as the objects have the same Id, merge() will merge any changes and only update what changed (or nothing).

merge() will need to load the object, so if you know the set of objects, you could optimize it by pre-loading them in a single query.

Comment: How does this work with nested objects? My outer object has an ID as does another object contained within the outer one. For this to work I'd need to ensure the IDs on the inner and outer objects are the same as what is in the DB? My use case is always to read the data from an external source then update in into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You lack some idnetifier. Create a column in your tables which will represent the source whcih  you have created the object from( filename, or line of a particular file - you haven't described the format).

Then you will be able to read the object from database, update it with the new values and write it to the db back.